# How to get a PID's children in c# at a usable speed

Tags: c#, process, children

There are several (tons) of resources for finding parent/child processes from a PID.  Too many to even list.  I am finding that they are all incredibly slow.

Let's say I'm trying to implement a simple version of Process Explorer.  I can enumerate all the processes easily and quickly with Process.GetProcesses().  However, getting the parent/child relationships takes *forever*.

I have tried using the NtQueryInformationProcess method, and found that this takes ~.1 seconds PER QUERY, that is, to get one parent from one process.  To get children you basically have to build the whole tree and run this on every running process.

I then tried using ManagementObject to query for a process's parent and found  it to be even slower at ~.12 seconds.

I tried going the other way and using ManagementObject to query the children directly rather than querying parents and building a tree.  Querying for the children took between .25 and .5 seconds PER QUERY.

With any of these methods, that means populating a model of the current process tree takes 6-15 full seconds.  That just seems crazy to me, like an order of magnitude higher than I would have guestimated.  I can open process explorer and the parent/child relationships in the whole tree are just right there, immediatly.

Is there something wrong with my computer to make it this slow?  Is this just a thing that for some reason takes way longer to discover than you'd think?  How can process explorer do it so fast?

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with this which is a significant improvement.  Since it's apparently WMI which is dog slow, I reduced it down to a single query for all processes and their parents, and then (with code) fill in the children so they are easily retrievable.

Notes on this code: it's a static class, sue me.  it's called ProcessTree, but the data is not stored as a tree, it just models the tree, again sue me.  also, there might be bugs, this is a proof of concept.

This gets the speed down to a third of a second, instead of 5-15 seconds.  Since this is still expensive, it caches data for the interval ispecified in 'timeout'.  This cache is not made to work with threads.

```
public static class ProcessTree
{
    private static Dictionary<int, ProcessTreeNode> processes;

    private static DateTime timeFilled = DateTime.MinValue;
    private static TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

    static ProcessTree()
    {
        processes = new Dictionary<int, ProcessTreeNode>();
    }

    public static List<int> GetChildPids(int pid)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > timeFilled + timeout) FillTree();
        return processes[pid].Children;
    }

    public static int GetParentPid(int pid)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > timeFilled + timeout) FillTree();
        return processes[pid].Parent;
    }

    private static void FillTree()
    {
        processes.Clear();
        var results = new List<Process>();

        string queryText = string.Format("select processid, parentprocessid from win32_process");
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryText))
        {
            foreach (var obj in searcher.Get())
            {
                object pidObj = obj.Properties["processid"].Value;
                object parentPidObj = obj.Properties["parentprocessid"].Value;
                if (pidObj != null)
                {
                    int pid = Convert.ToInt32(pidObj);
                    if (!processes.ContainsKey(pid)) processes.Add(pid, new ProcessTreeNode(pid));
                    ProcessTreeNode currentNode = processes[pid];

                    if (parentPidObj != null)
                    {
                        currentNode.Parent = Convert.ToInt32(parentPidObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (ProcessTreeNode node in processes.Values)
        {
            if (node.Parent != 0 && processes.ContainsKey(node.Parent)) processes[node.Parent].Children.Add(node.Pid);
        }
        timeFilled = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class ProcessTreeNode
{
    public List<int> Children { get; set; }
    public int Pid { get; private set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }

    public ProcessTreeNode(int pid)
    {
        Pid = pid;
        Children = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

I will leave the question not-answered in case someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could p/invoke `Process32First`, `Process32Next`, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`. The `PROCESSENTRY32` structures returned have a parent process id, which you could use to establish parent relationship. These API's are blazingly fast.